# Dynamic variable name R

Tags: r, variables, var

I have already read similar questions regarding the `assign` command. But it doesnt work for me.

Here is my code:

```
masums <- function(var) {
    lags <- var$p                    # number of lags in VAR
    eqn  <- length(var$varresult)    # number of equations in VAR
    dep  <- names(var$varresult)     # names of dependent variables

    for(i in 1:eqn) # compute coefficient matrices
        d <- dep[i]
        x <- paste("var$varresult$",d,"$coefficients",sep="")
        y <- as.matrix(GET THE VALUE OF "x" e.g. var$varresult$d$coefficients) # d="gap" for i=1
    }
    return(y)
}
```

Example: For i=1 d would have the value "gap", therefore I want the value of var$varresult$gap$coefficients.

var$varresult consists of elements of class "lm". Maybe the solution is easy and I am just to stressed to see it.
Hope someone can help.

Edit:
For a small example dataset:

```
library(vars)
y <- c(100*rnorm(100))
x <- seq(1,100,1)

vardata <- cbind(x,y)
var1    <- VAR(vardata,p=4,type="const")
var1$varresult$x$coefficients
```

Martin

Comment: You need to specify what "doesn't work". I see several potential problems here - (1) what are you doing with `x`? (2) you're only returning `y` from the last iteration of your loop - but you haven't explained what you're actually trying to do and what aspects of your current efforts aren't working.

Comment: I sense there's a better way of achieving what you're after. Can you provide us with a small reproducible example and desired output?

Comment: I have used R every day for 6 years, and never once found it necessary to use `assign`.  There is probably a more R-like way of doing things.  What is your real problem?

Comment: Yes I just extract the last coefficient matrix in this example. Of course this is not what I intend to do here later on. The problem is that I cannot use var$varresult$d$coefficients where d would be "gap" for the first lm object. It is not easy to make a reproduceable example, since I use a result of a VAR estimation wich is pretty big :/

Comment: The actual problem to be clear is, how can I retrive the value of an object, If I use a variable in its name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` to construct a nested variable access in a string is the completely wrong approach.

What you are missing is the fact that `x$y` can also be written as `x$['y']` (or `x$[['y']]`, depending whether you want a single value in a list, or a column in a data.frame), and here `'y'` is a *string*. So you can write this:

```
y <- as.matrix(var$varresult[[d]]$coefficients)
```

(assuming `var$varresult` is a list)